# Request more information with payment, after participant approval

Tags: civievent, online-registration

I am setting up an event that will use the 'Require participant approval' functionality of online event registration.

The way that I would like for the registration process to happen is:

The participant applies for the event, giving limited information. (e.g. name, email)

Once approved they receive an email with a link to the confirmation page which requests additional information, e.g lunch choice etc. from them as well as payment.

CiviCRM has almost all of this possible out of the box which is great, however the part that I can't see how to achieve is to request the extra info in the completion stage of their registration.

It is very important to us that we can take more information at this later stage, instead of requesting all the information upfront on application (the lunch choice was just a simplified example).

I have not seen any way this is possible through the UI, for example to add a profile or custom fields to this second stage of the participant approval process mentioned here.

Is this possible through the UI?
If not has anyone used an extension or some custom code, that could give me advice on where to start with this?

I am using Wordpress.

Comment: i think you might have to look in to doing the second step via Caldera forms (as I would be doing this via Webforms on a Drupal site). hope that gives you a hint

Comment: Thank you @petednz. I have had a brief look at Caldera, which looks to offer a lot more powerful functionality, it's a shame that they are being moved over to ninja forms. Sounds like drupal webforms is really the way to go with CiviCRM, I will consider migrating to drupal to get more control over these things.